# Does a class which is extending an abstract class still has to implement the interface that abstract class is implementing?: java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface-implementation

```
public abstract class ClassA implements ClassB{
}



public class ClassC extends ClassA implements ClassB{
}
```

Since class "ClassC" is extending class "ClassA", does "ClassC" still has to implement "ClassB"? Or "ClassB" is automatically implemented for class "ClassC"?

Comment: The latter, you "inherit" the parent classes' interfaces.

Comment: It already does, by inheritance. Whether you so declare it n the new class is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ClassA` is not `abstract` and fully implements `ClassB`, then `ClassC` inherits `ClassA`'s implementation and does not need to re-implement anything from `ClassB` unless it wants to override the behavior.

It also does not need to specify `implements ClassB`.  The following example is valid:

```
public static interface I { }
public static class A implements I { }
public static class B extends A { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    I b = new B();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need do implement again it is already implemented by the Product Class, i've created an example to show you

[image]

I created the method just to show you how it would work

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you implement the interface into the super class all the childs will have the Interface methods!
Hope it helps :)